# Getting data from different queries in a single report in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, report

I have a data table in MS access with the following columns:
ID  |  Name  |  Investigator | Open Date | Closed Date | Open/Closed

I am trying to create a report that has the total number of open cases, closed cases and pending cases grouped by the investigator name. Problem is that these three columns are filtered on on different things: Open Cases (on open date}, closed cases (on closed date) and pending cases (no date filter). Is there a proper way in which I can get all the data in one report without complicating things? Thanks!

Comment: Use each query to make a subreport, each of which appears in a consolidating report.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way out which doesn't involves sub-reports.

Comment: This is the purpose of sub-reports. This will be the simplest solution.

Comment: I have a problem doing that way. From the main report, I give the start and end date in the filter. This date filter needs to be applied to the open and closed cases sub-report. In both the sub-reports, I have given the start and end date place holders. By default, the main report's start and end date propagate to  only first sub-report place holders. How do I make the start and end date filter value of main report propagate to the other sub-reports?

Comment: Use the "Build..." function of each query to use the start and end date fields in their criteria.  For example, something like (syntax not guaranteed) `=Reports("mainReport").startdate`

Comment: Make three separate queries and join them with a UNION. You can add a constant column for marking the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT Investigator, 
       Sum(Abs(Not IsNull([Open Date]) And IsNull([Closed Date]))) AS OpenCases, 
       Sum(Abs(Not IsNull([Closed Date]))) AS ClosedCases, 
       Sum(Abs(IsNull([Closed Date]) And IsNull([Open Date]))) AS PendingCases
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Investigator
```

Put it in a query and save it; qInvestigatorSummary or something.  Then build your report from the query.

A couple of notes.
I am assuming that the empty date fields are null.  If it's not null you can test it other ways ([Open Date]='') or IsDate([Open Date]).  They'll all react a little differently based on what is in an empty cell.

Also I hope you are not naming your fields as you have indicated.  As a general rule you are much better off using only alpha numeric characters in your field names, with underscores if needed.  For example 'OpenDate' would be much better than 'Open Date' by just removing the spaces. 'open_date' would work too. Things like slashes 'Open/Closed' should be avoided at all costs.  You should also avoid using reserved words like 'Name'.  Databases have special uses for words like that and it can make a lot more work for you in the future.  Try to name your fields less ambiguously, for example 'Name' refers to the name of what?   UserName or CaseName would be much better.  Descriptive will serve you, and anyone that follows in your footsteps, better than short and unclear.